# Object PDF Viewer does not Render large File with over 2.0 MB in chrome

Tags: javascript, html, jsf

Sorry if this question might have been asked before but I am trying to show a preview of pdf document before upload and only work for pdf less than 1Mb of data. Any data above this does not seem to show in my browser. I am using chrome. Here is my XHTML code which works for less than 1MB pdf files.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
    <h:head>
        <title>Facelet Title</title>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            //<![CDATA[ 
         

          
            function renderPDF(input)
            {

                if (input.files && input.files[0])
                {
                    var reader = new FileReader();
                    reader.onload = function (e)
                    {
                  
                        $('#p_viewer').attr('src', e.target.result);
                    };
                    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
                }

            }
            
    
            //]]> 
        </script>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <h:form id="uploader_form" enctype="multipart/form-data">

                    <h:inputFile value="#{up.file}" onchange="renderPDF(this)" />

                </h:form>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <p:outputPanel id="out">
                    <iframe frameborder="0"   height="600"  width="100%" id="p_viewer" type="application/pdf">
                        
                    </iframe>
                  
                </p:outputPanel>

            </div>
        </div>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

Or is there another way to show pdf document in JSF prior to upload submit button is clicked?